# Inserting window form records to sql database in C#

Tags: c#

I am having trouble in posting records from my window form to my SQL database.

When I am in the Debug mode, I see the data supplied but I don't see it in my SQL database, what else can I do?

Below is my code snippet:

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost;" +
         "Initial Catalog=EmploymentDb;Integrated Security=true; User Instance=False";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

            command.Connection = connection;

        //command.CommandText
                string sql = "INSERT INTO EmploymentDb " +
               "(Id,Title, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Gender, Address, Email, StateOfResidence, City, MobileNumber, DateOfBirth, HomePhoneNumber, YearOfGraduation, StateOfOrigin, LGA, NYSCCertificateNumber, SchoolAttended, NYSCStatus, Eligibility) VALUES " +
               "(@Id, @Title, @LastName, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @Gender, @Address, @Email, @StateOfResidence, @City, @MobileNumber, @DateOfBirth, @HomePhoneNumber, @YearOfGraduation, @StateOfOrigin, @LGA, @NYSCCertificateNumber, @SchoolAttended, @NYSCStatus, @Eligibility)";

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

                    //To INSERT and Retrieve records IN A db
                    var query = "SELECT Id, Title FROM EmploymentDb";
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", txtID.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", comboBoxtTitle.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", txtMiddleName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", comboBoxGender.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StateOfResidence", comboBoxState.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", comboBoxCity.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber", txtMobileNo.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", dateTimePickerDOB.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhoneNumber", txtHomePhone.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearOfGraduation", comboBoxYearOfGraduation.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StateOfOrigin", comboBoxStateOfOrigin.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LGA", comboBoxLGA.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NYSCCertificateNumber", txtNYSCCertNumder.Text); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolAttended", txtSchoolAttended.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NYSCStatus", comboBoxNYSCStatus.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Eligibility", cbxAgeLimit.Text);

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds, "Employment");


                    FillControls();
                    int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show(affectedRows + "Row inserted!");

                    btnNext.Enabled = true;
                    //btnPrevious.Enabled = true;      

                    //Calling Window Work experience page
                    WorkExperience frm = new WorkExperience();
                    frm.ShowDialog();
                }


     try
     {
         connection.Open();
         int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         if (result > 0)
             MessageBox.Show("Successfully added!");
         else
             MessageBox.Show("Failed to add!");
     }
     catch (SqlException ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("An error has occured!");
     }
     finally
    {
        connection.Close();
         }
   }

     private void FillControls()
        {

        }
```

Comment: you using `Data Source=localhost;` is it true? By default visual studio show you `./localDb`

Comment: Yes it's "true"

Comment: How do you verify that the data is not inserted?

Comment: Can you explain the code logic? I see that the `command` object  does not `CommandText` property assigned to it. What is the user of populating dataset `ds` ? Do you see messagebox with message `{numberofrows} row inserted`?

Comment: You create your SQL query in a local field called `sql`, but you never update the `command.CommandText` of the command that you are executing at the end... Is the code you posted your actual code, or is this some kind of copy/paste typo?

Comment: Your executed query looks like a select rather than insert : `var query = "SELECT Id, Title FROM EmploymentDb";
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);`